# Google maps - Current position disappears once any marker is clicked

Tags: google-maps

I have a question, as the title says, basically the situation is that I have populated some positions using a xml file (from a database),

So when I click on any marker, my current location marker disappears, not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
function initMap() {


var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
  zoom: 12
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});



// Try HTML5 geolocation.
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var pos = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude
    };

    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
    map.setCenter(pos);
  }, function() {
    handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  });
} else {
  // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
  handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
}

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
  downloadUrl('https://www.mysite/dataMaps.php', function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
      var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
      var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
      var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
          parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

      var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
      var strong = document.createElement('strong');
      strong.textContent = name
      infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
      infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

      var text = document.createElement('text');
      text.textContent = address
      infowincontent.appendChild(text);
      var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        label: icon.label
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        //map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

      });
    });
  });



}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your "current position" shown by/in the infowindow?

Comment: Hi, yes at the veryfirst time it appears as: 'Location found.' and my marker is present, but if I select any other marker populated by the te data base my current position (the one that says: 'Location found.') disappears

Comment: You only have one infowindow (it gets reused by the marker click function).  If you want to keep the original infowindow around, create a new one to use for the markers (and probably disable the click to close functionality on the original one...)

Comment: I have wraped it in a function but now my data base markers dissapired, I'm not able to share my code here.But var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { and var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
 and  if (navigator.geolocation) { added in a function

Answer (score 0):

I see what you say, I just added

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

inside the marker onclick function.

```
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
     var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
```

**var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map}**

The issue is now that once I click on any marker, the infowindow of any of them is always present, so If I click on all of them, now all of them are present and I need to close them manually